# How can I manage page within page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
  height: 45,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedCard = 1;
          });
        },
        child: ExploreList(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: selectedCard == 1 ? orange : Colors.transparent,
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          title: 'Painting',
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedCard = 2;
          });
        },
        child: ExploreList(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: selectedCard == 2 ? orange : Colors.transparent,
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          title: 'Drawing',
        ),
      ),
```

The cards in the image above.

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.brush,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 151, 47),
                          ),
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          'French Romantism',
                          style: artTitle,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Family Gallery',
                          style: artSubtitle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Image.asset('assets/images/horizontal.jpg'),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'Art Institute of Chicago',
                          style: artTitle,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Chicaho IL. Sep 1 - Nov 20',
                          style: artSubtitle,
                        ),
                        trailing: FaIcon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.ticket,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
```

The code with the images and information I want to show on the relevant page.

I have 3 questions about this code. First, this list is a list of 3 identical images and information. I want to add different images and information to this list. How should I create my own list for this?
Secondly, when I click on the cards above, I can see the same list. But I want to see a separate list for each option, how can I edit it?
Third, there is too much space between the cards I created as options (Painting, Drawing etc.) and the cards that are lists. So, I want to bring the first post in the list closer to the above options. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need some sort of List data structure to get different images/text. Right now you are rendering static data.

```
class Exhibition{
 String title;
 String subTitle;
 String imageAsset;
 String artTitle;
 String artSubtitle;

Exhibition({required this.title, required this.subTitle, required this.imageAsset, required this.artTitle, required this.artSubtitle})
}

//Add your own custom exhibitions here
List<Exhibition> exhibitionsList = [
 Exhibitions(title:'', subtitle: '', etc, etc)

]

ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: exhibitionsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Exhibition model = exhibitionsList[index];

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.brush,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 151, 47),
                          ),
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          model.title,
                          style: artTitle,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          model.subTitle,
                          style: artSubtitle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Image.asset(model.imageAsset),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          model.artTitle,
                          style: artTitle,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          model.artSubtitle,
                          style: artSubtitle,
                        ),
                        trailing: FaIcon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.ticket,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
```

2. You will need other custom List models to have different data for each option. Use the example above to do something similair.
3. Reduce the padding here... I would suggest using Listview.seperated() function instead, rather than adding padding like this..

```
Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
```

Example of separated listview.

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: exhibitionsList.length,
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
 return SizedBox(height:10);
},
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    //Put your item builder things here
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I just couldn't figure out how to show a list of that option when another option is clicked.